# How to make div with background-image act like like <img "width=100%"/>

Tags: css, background-image, background-size

I have this code:

```css
div#fond {
  background-image: url('https://www.thetileapp.com/images/Purse_Tabletop-46.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="fond">
    ABCD
  </div>
  <br>
  <img src="https://www.thetileapp.com/images/Purse_Tabletop-46.jpg" width="100%" />
</body>

</html>
```

How can i do to make the div have the same behaviour than the img, so that the height of the div adapt itself to the width of the window.
For the moment, the height is adapted to div content.

Answer (score 3):

For percentage height to work, you must add `html, body {height: 100%;}` otherwise the browsers will not be able to calculate a percentage of `auto` which is the default. Percentage heights work based on parnet, when the parent is body/html, you need to add the rules I mentioned.

Alternatively, you can use the viewport units (`vw`/`vh`), like:

```
div#fond {
  background-image: url('https://www.thetileapp.com/images/Purse_Tabletop-46.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reflexion aziz but, I'e tested the 2 solutions but none of them give the result, a div acting like "<img width="100%">"
I presume the solution is more sophisticated...

Comment: Have a look at my demo: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/nvdm4rrd/ it works as expected

Comment: Thanks Aziz for your perseverance. I've make some modification to your fiddle to add "<img src" under the div to see the difference. At this address: https://jsfiddle.net/nvdm4rrd/4/ As you can see, the img is resized in both height and width when you move the separator of jsfiddle to the right. But in the div, the background-image is cropped.

Comment: @coutiereric I see what you mean. It's just that 100% of viewport height is not the same as the actual image's height... do you want the `div` to have a fixed height or dynamic height based on background image? You could try `100% 100%` instead of `cover` for `background-size` but this will stretch the image: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/vvhhuppv/

Comment: Holy cow, I didn't know `vh` and `vw` were a thing. That saved me a ton of headaches.